# Criteria API Real time Use in Java project

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria, criteria-api

In real time Java project while you use hibernate do you prefer Criteria API or HQL.
And when to use which one.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that Criteria API can be used when you have to build different query for each request depending of external conditions. For example that can be search API with multiple (variable) conditions. HQL is a predefined query with predefined set of conditions. If you want to use HQL with variable conditions, than you have to build you query concatenating strings that is complicated task. And possible that SQL injection can be made with HQL.